# Invalid Stream Header

Tags: java, file-io, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read in a binary file supplied by my teacher, and I keep getting  java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Invalid Stream Header. How do I fix this?

```
public class BinaryPart {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
  String fileName = "HW5Input.bin";
    try{
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("There was a problem opening the file: " + e);
        System.exit(0);
    }try{
        byte var1 = inputStream.readByte();
        inputStream.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("There was an issue reading from the file: " + e);
        System.exit(0);
    }
  }}
```

Comment: Are you trying to read a persisted object or a binary file? ObjectInputStream is used to read persisted Java objects stored in Java's serialization format, so that's probably the reason for the error (that file of yours is not a persisted object).

Comment: OH! Thank you! Do you happen to know how I can read in a straight binary file? When I google it, only code similar to what I have above comes up. Thank you!!

Comment: Omit the `ObjectInputStream` altogether.  Just read from the `FileInputStream`.

Comment: Or change it to a `DataInputStream` if you want the binary APIs.